# CentOS 7 SSSD AD with Samba Share

Tags: centos, samba, cifs, sssd

I followed [this site's tutorial](http://www.hexblot.com/blog/centos-7-active-directory-and-samba) to install SSSD (without WinBind) to join a Windows Server 2008 domain. And it is a great success. Before that I was trying to use Zentyal to set up share folders but no luck ... Zentyal always show errors ...

I wanted to use GUI to complete the job but when I failed in Webmin Samba and Zentyal, the only option I left is to set up one by one with command, and implement the smb.conf by hand. Luckily the tutorial can join the domain without any problems, and I can setup the Samba share.

---

Here is the smb.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = ADDOMAIN
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        security = ads
        # encrypt passwords = yes
        # passdb backend = tdbsam
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        realm = addomain.tld
        access based share enum = yes

        # this is just a member server
        domain master = no
        local master = no
        preferred master = no

        # in my test network I could not get AD authentication for smb shares to work
        # without adding "kerberos method = secrets and keytab"
        kerberos method = secrets and keytab

        # Add the IPs / network ranges / subnets allowed acces to the server in general.
        # this is not a nesessary entry but in general a good idea.
        # hosts allow = 127. your local network info

        # log files split per-machine:
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

        # enable the following line to debug:
        # log level = 3
        # maximum size of 50KB per log file, then rotate:
        max log size = 50

        # Not interested in printers
        load printers = no
        cups options = raw

        # This stops an annoying message from appearing in logs
        printcap name = /dev/null

        # File Shares under valid users I put a group if you create a group for samba in # active directory and add users to it those users will be able to access smb
        # shares from this server over the network.

[guest]
        comment = guest
        path = /home/samba/guest
        public = yes
        readonly = no
        writable = yes
        guest ok = yes

[admin]
        comment = admin
        path = /home/samba/admin
        public = no
        readonly = no
        writable = yes
        guest ok = no
        valid users = @"admingp@addomain.tld"
```

There is a user, ADDOMAIN\admintest (or admintest@addomain.tld) login a Windows PC and try to access the "Admin" share folder but couldn't grant access. The log says "NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED". But I am sure that the account is in the group.

To make sure the AD and the user info is synced to my CentOS 7, I changed the valid users from `@"admingp@addomain.tld"` to `"admintest@addomain.tld"`. The user can access the share folder.

Then what I tried to troubleshoot is, use the `id` command. I have modified the sssd.conf no need to use full qualified name. So ...

```
# id admintest

  uid=821800500(admintest) gid=821800513(domain users) groups=821800513(domain users)
```

This is simply strange. Yeah this account is in the domain users but it still have some other groups which belong to including the "admingp".

Then I used the "getent" command to show group members.

```
# getent group admingp
  admingp:*:821808307:administrator,admintest,ben, ... (etc)
```

There it is, admintest is in the group. Because it also in the domain users group and I try again to modify the smb.conf, the valid users changed to `@"domain users@addomain.tld"` and guess what? The share folder is accessible.

So I can conclude that the smb.conf is fine, the AD authentication is fine. But as you noticed, `id admintest` only displays the first matched group. The others are skipped so I can't set the share folder with Group Permission. And I have dozens of groups and dozens of share folders there I can't simply implement it one by one.

And I final test for the `id` command. The Linux account "support" belongs to 2 groups. One is "support" itself and the other is "wheel".

```
# id support
  uid=1000(support) gid=1000(support) groups=1000(support),10(wheel)
```

Linux users aren't affected. So ... what went wrong? I have attached the sssd.conf here. Please have a look.

```
[sssd]
domains = addomain.tld
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/addomain.tld]
ad_domain = addomain.tld
krb5_realm = ADDOMAIN.TLD
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True

# use_fully_qualified_names = True
# fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d

use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u

enumerate = True
access_provider = simple
# access_provider = ldap
```

Thanks very much in advanced.